# How to read process Output Message from process within the process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, console-application

I am running an exe through commandline and getting following output.

> **C:\Users\sysadmin>C:\Users\sysadmin\Desktop\New_folder\Setup\PatchInstaller.exe
>   --mode=silent**
>
> C:\Users\sysadmin Begin Setup UI mode: Silent Error :
>   Another instance running, Only a single instance can be run at a time.
>   Exit Code: 11

i am running this through System.daignostics.process.

My issue is **PatchInstaller.exe** calling another process and the output of that nested process is what is visible with cmd. but the same result and exit code i am not able to get through Process object of **PatchInstaller.exe**.
Is there any way of getting output of process running within process?
Following is the code i have tired...

```
            string command = @"C:\Users\sysadmin\Desktop\Setup\PatchInstaller.exe";
            string result = string.Empty;
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command + " --mode=silent);
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new Process();
            procStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            procStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            // Do not create the black window.
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwd))
            {
                procStartInfo.Domain = domain;
                procStartInfo.UserName = user;

                System.Security.SecureString ss = new System.Security.SecureString();
                foreach (char c in pwd) { ss.AppendChar(c); }
                procStartInfo.Password = ss;
            }

            proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(procStartInfo);

            proc.ErrorDataReceived += delegate(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs errorLine)
            {
                if (errorLine.Data != null) result += "error:" + errorLine.Data +;

            };
            proc.OutputDataReceived += delegate(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs outputLine)
            {
                if (outputLine.Data != null) result += outputLine.Data +;

            };
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("PatchInstaller");
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
            }

            proc.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `ProcessStartInfo` but I have used `Process` before and the way to get the information out of the standard output is shown as below, I assume it should be a similar way just by accessing the `StandardOutput`

```
Process cmd = new Process();

cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();

cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();

var output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
    const int MAX_EXIT_WAIT_TIME = 3000;
    // Fill needed data
    string username = "";
    string password = "";
    string domain = "";
    string appName = "";

    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
    var appFullPath = Path.Combine(dir, appName);
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(appFullPath);
    psi.UserName = username;
    var securePass = new System.Security.SecureString();
    foreach (var c in password)
        securePass.AppendChar(c);
    psi.Password = securePass;
    psi.Domain = domain;
    psi.LoadUserProfile = false;
    psi.WorkingDirectory = dir;
    psi.Arguments = "";
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    // Create Process object, but not start it!
    var proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = psi;
    StringCollection values = new StringCollection();
    DataReceivedEventHandler outputDataReceived = (o, e) =>
    {
        lock (values)
            values.Add(e.Data);
    };
    try
    {
        proc.OutputDataReceived += outputDataReceived;
        // Only here we start process
        if (!proc.Start())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn't start app");
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.WaitForExit(MAX_EXIT_WAIT_TIME);
    }
    finally { proc.OutputDataReceived -= outputDataReceived; }
    Console.WriteLine("Read {0} ", values.Count);
    foreach (var item in values)
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", item);
```

Comment: PatchInstaller.exe it will excute silently then it  will invoke other process inside of PatchInstaller.exe and will get C:\Users\sysadmin>Begin Setup
UI mode: Silent
Error : Conflicting Processes running.
Exit Code: 19 So I need to read this piece of line. Here I got stuck .

Comment: I haven't understood what did you said.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But I am not looking for the same which u done here.  This is a workable code when the exe is directly  executing and giving the output below of command-line. 
Here my exe is running and it will execute the below line first,
C:\Users\sysadmin\Desktop\New_folder\Setup\PatchInstaller.exe --mode=silent
Now PatchInstaller.exe is internally executing other process, I am expecting the output from this internal process,
(EX :C:\Users\New_folder\Setup\PatchInstaller.exe --mode=silent (Enter) C:\Windows\system32>Begin Setup Exit Code:19;(Need to read this line.)

Comment: Do you want to redirect an output not the created process, but it's child? If yes, I think it's impossible without some hacks.